# Understanding Cron in Springboot, to automate sending an email

Tags: java, spring-boot, cron, scheduled-tasks

There's a lot of information out there on Cron and I am getting slightly confused. Most of the information is solely about setting the scheduled cron annotation. I have never used SpringBoot Scheduling before. What I am trying to do is set an email to be sent once a month, say the 15th of every month. I've sent emails before using EmailService and Helpers. Is it right to combine these two methods, or should I be setting up the email template and sending of the email a different way? What I have is not sending the email (when I change to todays date and time).Can anyone tell me why it's not sending at the scheduled time, am I missing some piece of code or is this not the way to do it with Scheduling? I've used this method of sending email with email service before and its worked, so has to be something wrong with the way I set up the scheduler.  Anyone have an idea on why it's not running the sendReminder() at scheduled time?

This is what I have in my code so far...
Controller:

```
@Controller
public class MailController {
    @Autowired
    LicenseRepository licenseRepository;

    @Autowired
    InsuranceRepository insuranceRepository;

    @Autowired
    EmailService emailService;

    @Scheduled(cron = "0 15 10 15 * ?")
    public void sendReminder(){
        License license = new License();
        Insurance insurance = new Insurance();
        Mail mail = new Mail();
        mail.setFrom("no-reply@gmail.com");
        mail.setTo(new String[]{"myemail@gmail.com"});
        mail.setSubject("Policy Renewal Notice");

        Map<String, Object> mailModel = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        mail.setModel(mailModel);

        try {
            emailService.sendSimpleMessage(mail, license, insurance);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/email")
    public String email(){
        return "emailMessage";
    }
}
```

And the email service:

```
@Service
public class EmailService{

    private JavaMailSender javaMailSender;

    @Autowired
    public EmailService(JavaMailSender javaMailSender){
        this.javaMailSender = javaMailSender;
    }

    @Autowired
    private SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine;

    public void sendSimpleMessage(Mail mail, License license, Insurance insurance) throws MessagingException, IOException {
        MimeMessage message = javaMailSender.createMimeMessage();
        MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message,
                MimeMessageHelper.MULTIPART_MODE_MIXED_RELATED,
                StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());

        helper.addAttachment("Mail_Icon.png", new ClassPathResource("static/images/Mail_Icon.png"));

        Context context = new Context();
        context.setVariables(mail.getModel());
        context.setVariable("license",license);
        context.setVariable("insurance",insurance);
        String html = templateEngine.process("emailMessage", context);

        helper.setTo(mail.getTo());
        helper.setText(html, true);
        helper.setSubject(mail.getSubject());
        helper.setFrom(mail.getFrom());

        javaMailSender.send(message);
    }



}
```

And then finally the html email template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns:th="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>HTML Reminder Email</title>
    <style type="text/css">
  lots of styling here removed for easier reading
  </style>
</head>

<body bgcolor="#f6f8f1">
<table width="100%" bgcolor="#f6f8f1" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
            <table width="600" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                <tr>
                    <td>
            <![endif]-->
            <table bgcolor="#ffffff" class="content" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                <tr>
                    <td bgcolor="#6435c9" class="header">
                        <table width="70" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                            <tr>
                                <td height="70" style="padding: 0 20px 20px 0;">
                                    <img class="fix" src="cid:Mail_Icon.png" width="70" height="70" border="0" alt="" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                        <table width="425" align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                        <![endif]-->
                        <table class="col425" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%; max-width: 425px;">
                            <tr>
                                <td height="70">
                                    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="subhead" style="padding: 0">
                                                Policy Renewal Expiration Reminder
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                        </td>
                        </tr>
                        </table>
                        <![endif]-->
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="innerpadding borderbottom">
                        <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                            <tr class="emailRow">
                                <p>AFFILIATE NAME HERE</p>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="emailRow">
                                <p>Our Records indicate that your policy is up for renewal in 30 days. Please provide the updated proof of insurance to the Director of Operations by email: <a href="mailto:myemail@gmail.com">myemail@gmail.com</a>.  We appreciate your compliance. </p>
                                <p>Thank you,</p>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

This is where I put the Enable Scheduling annotation: in my main.java file

```html
@EntityScan(
  basePackageClasses = {ODbApplication.class, Jsr310JpaConverters.class}
)
@EnableScheduling
@SpringBootApplication
@Configuration
public class ODbApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
 @Override
 protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
  return application.sources(ODbApplication.class);
 }


 public static void main(String[] args) {
  SpringApplication.run(ODbApplication.class, args);
 }

 @Bean
 public FilterRegistrationBean securityDatabaseFilterRegistration(SecurityDatabaseFilter securityDatabaseFilter) {
  FilterRegistrationBean registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean(securityDatabaseFilter);
  registrationBean.setEnabled(false);
  return registrationBean;
 }

}
```

Comment: And your question / problem is? There is a lot of code which doesn't apply. As I read it you only have a question about the cron expression (so why all the other code). Also the `@EnableScheduling` should go on your `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class or another `@Configuration` class.

Comment: My question is why isn't it sending the email if I change the date and time to be scheduled to send today as a test. I moved the @EnableScheduling to where you said... maybe that was the problem as to why it wasn't working?

Comment: can you show the expression that you changed for today @Stacie

Comment: `@EnableScheduling` is required in configuration to process `@Scheduled` annotations. You, can, for example, build an app that has a scheduled processor in one spring boot app, but in others just acts as an on-demand method in another.

Comment: @Deadpool I updated the code to show where I put the Enable Scheduling annotation, in my main Java Class file. Moving it didn't help though. The email is still not being sent at the time I set it to.

Comment: @EnableScheduling will only enables the schedulers in spring, but it will not make your method to run as soon as you start the application, you need to write the corn expression for that or use fixedDelay for testing

Comment: @Deadpool Thank you, I understand you need both pieces, but for testing I have been changing my cron to todays date and time like so: @Scheduled(cron = "0 11 13 35  * ?") and that doesn't seem to work. So, it seems that it wont work every 15th day of every month if I cant get it to work today.

Comment: It says my sendReminder function is never used, so I am wondering why the cron annotation isnt working/calling that function at the specified time?

Comment: your corn expression is wrong, `@Scheduled(cron = "0 11 13 35 * ?")` this means start job at `1:11 PM` on 35th day of month which is invalid, to start it at specific time today use this `0 5 13 * * ?`  this means `1:05 PM` on everyday @Stacie

Comment: Thank you @Deadpool! Was misreading that! It runs now, although I'm getting a different error that I will try to figure out. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Understand the cron expression, it consists of six fields. `<year> field is optional.` [docs](https://www.baeldung.com/cron-expressions)

```
<second> <minute> <hour> <day-of-month> <month> <day-of-week> <year>
```

`*` means `all`

`?` means `any`

> @Scheduled(cron = "0 15 10 15 * ?")

You are cron expression is good and it will start at `10:15 AM` of 15th day of every month

> Is it right to combine these two methods ?

There is no harm in doing this, if this is not working then you are missing something

**@EnableScheduling** It will just enables the capability

> Enables Spring's scheduled task execution capability

**@Scheduled**

> An annotation that marks a method to be scheduled. Exactly one of the cron(), fixedDelay(), or fixedRate() attributes must be specified.